# React Native hot reloading result in full reload after upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Recently I have upgraded my React Native app from `0.48` to `0.55`. After upgrade, hot reloading is not working any more.

Any changes to files will result in a full reload of the app.
Tried to clear all `watchman` cache and `npm` cache and still no help.

I tried to create a new template app from `react-native init` and hot reloading is not working on it.

Comment: It seems you are not the only one my friend ... please follow this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18899

Comment: Seems the situation is a bit different. My situation is always full reload if there is a change in code. Not no reload after changes.

Comment: @flycloud7788 can you tell me how did u perform the upgrade process. Because my hot reloading is also not working after upgrade to 0.55. So, during the upgrade process I could have made some mistake I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get this solve by disabling `Live Reload` and enable only `Hot Reloading`.
In pervious version, I need to enable both `Live Reload` and `Hot Reloading` to make hot reloading working.

Comment: Cool, its good to see that you solve it, my question is, does hot reload work with react-native 0.55 ?, Its seems a lot of people are having trouble to make it work .... including me :)

Comment: Yes, hot reloading is working on react-native 0.55 in my project now